# Add a ‘protective’ MBR to LVM2 physical volume

Tags: linux, partitioning, mbr, lvm

Some time ago I made a mistake of converting whole hard drive into a LVM PV without making a partition first.

It doesn't cause any problems, but I want to be on the safe side (for example, Windows will happily suggest to partition such drive).

Moving files onto another drive and remaking the LVM is not an option. Is it is possible to add ‘protective’ MBR to that hard drive?

There is free first sector before PV starts. I tried dd'ing an MBR there, but that didn't work (LVM no longer recognized PV (there was just 'sdc1'), so I had to zero it back).

Comment: If the onboard tools for LVM don't allow you to add one it's likely that it's not possible. If you add a MBR it's likely that LVM expects some kind of loader.

Answer (score 1):

The reason that the PV wasn't recognized is because LVM looks for the PV signature at a specific offset on the disk/partition/file/whatever. In my case that's at offset 0x0200 and as you noted, there is some free space before this signature.

However, if you create a partition table, the disk management system will recognize this and start looking for partitions. If there are no partitions, no LVM checks will be performed. If there is a partition it must start at a minimum of sector 1 (0 is the bootsector/MBR), and now you have a problem because everything in your volume has shifted one sector down (i.e. de PV signature is now at offset 0x0000).

You may be able to force the LVM subsystem to recognize PV signatures by supplying the whole disk device to pvscan, e.g.

```
pvscan /dev/sdc
```

but you have to add this manually to your startup configuration in stead of relying on the autodetect feature of LVM.